# JavaFX 8 Custom TableCell implementation is rendering three times

Tags: java, javafx-8, tablecell

I've developed a simple custom TableCell to enable the edition of the values in a table. The behaviour of the component is show a [BigDecimalTextField](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/blob/2.2/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/scene/control/BigDecimalField.java) no matter if the user is editing or not that cell, it should enable the edition all the time. The component is working fine, there is only a strange problem: when the table is rendered, instead of show only a single line, three lines are shown:

[image: Rendering three times]

The code of the component is this:

```
public class BigDecimalEditingCell extends TableCell {

    private BigDecimalField spinner = new BigDecimalField(new BigDecimal("0.00"));
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> campoLigado = null;

    public BigDecimalEditingCell() {
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        createField();
    }

    private void createField() {
        spinner.setStepwidth(new BigDecimal("0.01"));
        spinner.setMinValue(new BigDecimal("0.00"));
        spinner.setFormat(NumberFormat.getInstance());
        spinner.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        criarBind();
        setGraphic(spinner);
        setText(null);
    }

    private void criarBind() {
        ObservableValue<BigDecimal> valor = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
        if (valor != null) {
            ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> propriedade = (ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>) valor;
            if (campoLigado == null) {
                spinner.numberProperty().bindBidirectional(propriedade);
                campoLigado = propriedade;
            } else if (campoLigado != propriedade) {
                spinner.numberProperty().unbindBidirectional(campoLigado);
                spinner.numberProperty().bindBidirectional(propriedade);
                campoLigado = propriedade;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

If I use the default [TextFieldTableCell](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html), the table is rendered correctly. I have another component (like this) that uses JavaFX's [DatePicker](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) and the same problem happens.
What I'm doing wrong?

**ADDED**

Here is the usage of this component:

```
public class ControladorPainelFormaPagamento extends ControladorPainelSubmeter {

    @FXML
    private TableView<ParcelaBean> tabela;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ParcelaBean, LocalDate> colunaVencimento;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ParcelaBean, BigDecimal> colunaValor;
    private FormaPagamentoBean bean;

    .
    .
    .

    private void configurarColunaValor() {
        colunaValor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ParcelaBean, BigDecimal>("valor"));
        colunaValor.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ParcelaBean, BigDecimal>, TableCell<ParcelaBean, BigDecimal>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<ParcelaBean, BigDecimal> call(TableColumn<ParcelaBean, BigDecimal> parcelaBeanStringTableColumn) {
                return new BigDecimalEditingCell();
            }
        });
    }

    private void configurarColunaVencimento() {
        colunaVencimento.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ParcelaBean, LocalDate>("dataVencimento"));
    }

    public void carregar(ModoExibicao modoExibicao, FormaPagamentoBean formaPagamento) {
        this.bean=formaPagamento;
        tabela.setItems(bean.getParcelas());
        .
        .
        .
    }

    .
    .
    .

}
```

I've checked, inclusive using debug, if there was more than one bean in the list used by the table. Every time only one was there.

Comment: Seems that the your table has two additional entries for "vencimento" that are `null` or "". Can you show us how your table gets the data for this column? (like what `CellValueFactory` is used for this column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at another table in the same system and noticed this: when there is no item in the table, no one row is rendered.
[image: empty table]

but when you add just one row, the table renders empty row until reach the height of the table (repair the light grey rows):

[image: table with a row]

So, it was obvious that the extra rows were added by TableView, this way a simple null check solve the problem:

```
public class BigDecimalEditingCell extends TableCell {

    private BigDecimalField element = new BigDecimalField(new BigDecimal("0.00"));
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> campoLigado = null;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item,empty);
        if (getIndex() < getTableView().getItems().size() && !empty) {
            createField();
            createBind();
            setGraphic(element);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            removeBind();
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: you probably want to check for empty (vs. item == null). Also not, that it is bad programming style to widen method scope without reason: updateItem is meant to be used exclusively by subclasses, so making it public is wrong

Comment: my pleasure :-) Just seeing it now: you call super with empty == false, typo or intention?

Comment: hmm ... that looks fishy: it's strongly recommended to call super.updateItem because there is much internal cleanup happening